# Can I position an element absolutely based on it's own bottom edge?

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

I need to position an element so that it's *just* off the top of the screen (this will be a menu that slides down). I can, of course, use `position: absolute` and `top: 0px` but that will position by element based on my elements *top* edge.

Can I do the same but using my elements *bottom* edge?

Example:

```
#foo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  }
```

Will give me this:

```
-------------------------------------------
|              |                          | 
|   id="foo"   |        <body>            | 
----------------                          | 
|                                         | 
|                                         | 
-------------------------------------------
```

But is there a way to get this with CSS:

```
----------------
|              |      
|   id="foo"   |  
-------------------------------------------
|                                         | 
|                       <body>            | 
|                                         | 
|                                         | 
|                                         | 
-------------------------------------------
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to position a div with an unknown height (as the content will be variable) to the very top of the document using said div's *bottom* edge rather than the top.

Or is this not something CSS can handle by itself?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you want to position the element `100%` from the `bottom`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6v41sLog/)

```
#foo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
}
```

```css
.parent {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 75px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.child {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: aha! Yes, that's exactly it! That never occurred to me!

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it is by using `translateY(-100%)`:

```css
div {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  background: red;
}
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lacinia porta lacus ac egestas. Nam et elit lacus. Aliquam elementum felis imperdiet arcu commodo sollicitudin. Maecenas quis lectus in risus semper venenatis. Vestibulum eu bibendum diam. Cras
  aliquam elit sit amet dui vehicula, sit amet dignissim nulla convallis. Integer finibus, nisl maximus accumsan congue, ligula eros efficitur magna, ac gravida sapien dolor at leo. Morbi tempus ex lacus. Maecenas fermentum ut nisl at tincidunt. Etiam
  aliquet a ex vitae posuere. Nam ultrices tortor a congue ullamcorper. Quisque sit amet cursus magna, a finibus mauris. Duis at placerat orci, vitae ultrices dolor. Cras posuere, arcu ut ornare pharetra, neque justo aliquam orci, sodales viverra mi massa
  a quam. Morbi sollicitudin justo sapien, congue feugiat arcu vehicula et. Integer faucibus leo sit amet enim efficitur, ac laoreet lectus eleifend. Donec sit amet risus massa. Ut et nunc augue. Cras efficitur tellus sapien, nec viverra leo semper sed.
  Vivamus ut sollicitudin metus. Nulla et bibendum sapien, vel consequat lorem. Phasellus mi diam, fringilla sed iaculis in, aliquam non lorem. Integer ac vestibulum massa, sed aliquet dui. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse congue tortor ut vestibulum dignissim.
  Vestibulum quis est id est consectetur ultricies. Aliquam vitae suscipit purus.
</div>
```

Comment: 1+.. I think this approach can be more flexible.. for instance, with a `:hover` transition: http://jsfiddle.net/9qw2305x/

Comment: I like this! This might fit my need perfectly.